# Python - Base class' constructor is overriden

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

As explained in [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance), `super` can be used in multiple inheritance as well, as it will look for the attribute in both parents. But what attribute? The subclass already includes a `super` (if you look at the code below). How do I specify the attribute I want? I want `Error`'s constructor.

```
class Error(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

class AddDialog(sized_controls.SizedDialog, Error):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Error.__init__(self, *args)
        super(AddDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You can use `super`. In fact, that's exactly what it's for.

Comment: I've edited my question, could you take a look please?

Comment: This question is already been answered here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) I suppose. You need to understand what MRO is. You can find the MRO tree of a child class by `ChildClass.__mro__`. super function works with Class bound and Instance bound proxies.

Answer (score 1):

It is as easy as just trying it out:

```
class Error(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values
        print('Error')

class SizedDialog(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values
        print('SizedDialog')

class AddDialog(SizedDialog, Error):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('AddDialog')
        Error.__init__(self, *args)
        super(AddDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, `super()` is nothing else but going along the method resolution order (MRO) which you can get with `mro()`:

```
>>> AddDialog.mro()
[__main__.AddDialog, __main__.SizedDialog, __main__.Error, object]
```

So, in your case you call the `__init__()` of `Error` explicitly first. Then  `super()` will, in this specific case, find the `__init__()` of `SizedDialog` because it comes before `Error` in the MRO.

```
>>> a = AddDialog(10)
AddDialog
Error
SizedDialog
```

If you only use `super()` (no  call to `__init__()` of `Error`), you get only the `__init__()` of `SizedDialog`:

```
class AddDialog(SizedDialog, Error):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('AddDialog')
        super(AddDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

>>> a = AddDialog(10)
AddDialog
SizedDialog
```

Finally, if you only call the `__init__()` of `Error`, it is the only `__init__()` that is called.

```
class AddDialog(SizedDialog, Error):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('AddDialog')
        Error.__init__(self, *args)

>>> a = AddDialog(10)
AddDialog
Error
```

So your question:

> But what attribute?

has the answer:

**The one you call.**

It does not matter if you hard-wire the class, as done with `Error`, or let `super()` find the appropriate parent class, i.e. the next one in the MRO.
The only difference is that `super()` might call the `__init__()`of the grandparent class if the parent class does not have an `__init__()`.
But this is the intended behavior of `super()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question?